# my flash site often doesn't render until I refresh

Tags: apache-flex, flash, refresh, render

http://randomdorm.com

Our client communicates with a Rails backend to get login details and then logs into an Adobe LCCS server.  We have been cruising right along but around noon yesterday we developed a bug that causes the swf to not render until you refresh the page.  On subsequent refreshes it pops up right away.  The problem happened even when I disabled the code that checks in with the Rails server.

How could refreshing make a difference?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your users visit your page and the *swf starts playing before it's fully downloaded* and **stops** once it hits the last loaded frame and **doesn't continue to play** even when the swf is done loading.

When the user refreshes, **the swf has been cached** and they load the version they should have been seeing before.

An easy way to fix this is to put a `stop()` action on the first frame and then add a `Event.PROGRESS` listener to the main stage's `loaderInfo` object. When the events `bytesLoaded` match your `bytesTotal` then your swf is fully loaded and you can `play()` your swf at that point (or `gotoAndPlay()`.

**Example** *takes place on the first frame of your project*:

```
function loadProgressHandler(event:Event):void {
    if(event.bytesLoaded >= event.bytesTotal) {
        event.target.removeEventListener(Event.PROGRESS, this.loadProgressHandler);
        play();
    }
}

this.stop();
this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.PROGRESS, this.loadProgressHandler);
```